# Camel File Endpoint - Getting the file name

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route:

```
from("file:///u01/www/images/nonprofits-test?move=.done&preMove=.processing&filter=#nonpFileFilter&minDepth=2&recursive=true")
```

Later on in the route I need to access the origin file name. How do I get that information?  All of the headers contain information in like `${file:name}`, but not the actual file name.

Thanks in advance!

The base problem is that simple language is not being evaluated correctly in while running Camel with grails. This is being discussed further on the Camel user list.

Comment: Claus Ibsen Just trying to get an answer man :D I will post the list next time first

Answer (score 13, accepted):

there is a header called "CamelFileName" that stores this

see [camel-file2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) headers section for more details...

Comment: The proble is that CamelFileName was getting wiped out when I use preMove=.processing ... no idea why, but it is working w/o.  Not a good fix

Comment: @chrislovecnm if the standard header is being wiped out then you can copy the header and store the same as a new header property

Comment: The problem that I am having is because simple language is not being evaluated properly in grails

Comment: Link to documentation: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_message_headers

Answer (score 2):

If your simple language is not working it would be because you are not using `<simple`> tag try something like below.

```
     <route id="movedFailedFileForRetry">
        <from uri="file:///opt/failed?delete=true" />
        <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Moving failed file ${header.CamelFileName} for retry" />
        <choice>
            <when>
            <simple>${headers.CamelFileName} == 'file1.txt'</simple>
            <to uri="file:///opt/input1" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
            <to uri="file:///opt/input2" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
     </route>
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

${headers.CamelFileName} will provide you with the CamelFileName that is read for processing. We have many other header properties that you can find from the Camel Documentation.